# Hibernate 5 dependency has version conflict with itself on jboss-logging

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am implementing a jsf+spring+hibernate web app, I am using hibernate-entitymanager 5.2.13, this is my dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But I receive error `AbstractMethodError`. I get clue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102873/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-deploying-an-application-spring-4-mvchibernate-4) and use command `mvn enforcer:enforce` to find out the dependency conflict. This is the output:

```
Dependency convergence error for org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final paths to dependency are:
+-com.peter:Project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.13.Final
    +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final
and
+-com.peter:Project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.13.Final
    +-org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.13.Final
      +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final
and
+-com.peter:Project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.13.Final
    +-org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
      +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
```

Obviously, `hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.13.Final` has multiple version of `jboss-logging` which are `jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final` and `jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final` from different package. How can I fix this issue? Can it fix by excluding the one under `hibernate-commons-annotations` package? I try to exclude it like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

but it came out another error saying that jboss-logging class is required, I guess it is because the attempt above is to exclude all jboss-logging from the dependencies. What I want is to exclude the one from `org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations` only. Any idea?

Comment: explicitly adding the particular version of jboss-logging directly to your project....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dependencyManagement` in your **pom.xml** to choose version.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```